# Solr | Query that returns records where two fields do not have the same content

Tags: solr

## Issue

I am attempting to construct a query that compares the content of two fields.  The first is a org.apache.solr.schema.TextField type field, the other is a org.apache.solr.schema.ICUCollationField type field.  The field *should* be populated by same loading process as the first field, but I want to validate that.  A similar SQL query could be

```
SELECT * from TABLE where ColumnA <> ColumnB
```

I am running Solr 4.8.1 and Lucene 4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent for this in solr. You need to index a new boolean field and populate the value at index time if it is true/false depending on your logic. Then you can query on this field.